# Vector of lists displays different output every time I execute my program

Tags: c++

I have: `vector<list<Subway_Entrance*>> lineHashTable`

Here is my code to print the contents of the list from a given vector index:

```
list<Subway_Entrance*>::const_iterator it;
  for (it = lineHashTable[indexOfCell].begin(); it != lineHashTable[indexOfCell].end(); ++it)
      cout << (*it)->getSubwayName() << endl;
```

When I execute the program, sometimes it'll print the contents in the list (which is what I want) and other times it'll print everything in my vector.

Is this some sort of overflow issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: When you say "everything in your vector" I'm guessing you mean every entry in lineHashTable, which is implemented as a vector? Also, does it print every list node for every entry in the vector when this happens? The code you posted looks right, so it is likely that the initialization for these objects is not correct. As stated already, try to post a minimal version of the code that can compile.